# General treatments of the problem of extending a functor from a small category to its power set to an endofunctor on it?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, mathematical-writing

Suppose you analyse a small category $\mathsf{C}$ whose set of objects you again denote by $\mathsf{C}$. Suppose you have found a natural categorical structure on $2^{\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}$ (having much to do with the category $\mathsf{C}$). Suppose you have also found a functor $F\colon\mathsf{C}\rightarrow $ $2^{\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}$ important to you.
Suppose you would like to construct an endofunctor $\overline{F}\colon 2^{\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}\rightarrow2^{\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}$ naturally 'extending' $F$, at least in the sense that

$\overline{F}(\{O\})=F(O)$  $\quad$(point.condition)

for each object $O$ of $\mathsf{C}$.
Suppose you try this by defining $\overline{F}$ on objects of $2^{\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}$ by doing the most obvious: taking the image (in the set-map-sense) under $F$ of any given set of objects of $\mathsf{C}$. This might or might not work out to give an endofunctor, depending on how the category with set of objects $2^{\mathsf{C}}$ is defined. This is not an 'extension problem' in the most elementary sense of the term, since $\mathsf{C}$ is not a subset of $2^{\mathsf{C}}$, but a member.

> **Question 0.** Are there *general* treatments of this particular kind of functor extension problem that you would recommend?
>
> **Question 1.** Is there a usual technical term for this extension problem, and is there a, in some precise sense, canonical construction of the endofunctor $\overline{F}$?

I have seen this process once in the literature, but in a special case, and have forgotten where. Now I need it in my own work, and would like to read general theoretical treatments of it. I am aware of the importance and relevance of embedding a small categories $\textsf{C}$ into its *presheaf* category $\widehat{\mathsf{C}}$, which $2^{\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}$ is a subcategory of, but could not find a treatment specifically relevant to the extension problem described above. I would like not to explicitly describe my specific problem, not to bias the question and keep in general.

Very roughly speaking, the motivation comes from a problem in algebraic geometry, with

$\mathsf{C}$ corresponding to some sort of variety equipped with a notion of morphisms between its points,

the points of $\mathsf{C}$ parametrize a notion $S$ of `set of equations' each of whose possible solutions is again a point of $\mathsf{C}$,

$F$ describes the correspondence

($\mathsf{C}\ni O \mapsto F(O) = $ set of all solutions to the set of equations $S(O)$ $\in$ $2^{\mathsf{C}}$)

The goal is to extend $F$ to an endofunctor of the kind described above which formalizes the correspondence

($2^{\mathsf{C}}\ni \mathbb{O} \mapsto \overline{F}(\mathbb{O}) = $ set of all solutions to the set of equations $\bigcup_{O\in\mathbb{O}}S(O)$ $\in$ $2^{\mathsf{C}}$)

Moreover, I know at least one $O\in\mathsf{C}$ with $F(O)=\emptyset$.

Therefore,another necessary condition on the endofunctor $\overline{F}$ is

$\overline{F}(\mathsf{C})=\emptyset$.

Comment: If you don't forget that $\sf C$ is a category you can endow $2^{\sf C}$ with a category structure in a pretty much standard way: it is the category of functors ${\sf C}\to 2$ and natural transformations. It's up to you now to say whether $2=\{0,1\}$ or $2=\{0\le 1\}$, but in both cases it is a category ($\sf C\times C$ in the first case, and something a [little bit more complicated](https://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Distributors+and+barrels) in the other case.

Comment: I'll just throw an irresponsible answer, ok? If you can find a functor $y\colon {\sf C}\to 2^{\sf C}$ out of the Yoneda embedding (let's say for example that you send $c\in\sf C$ to the composition ${\sf C} \overset{y}\to [{\sf C}^\text{op}, {\bf Sets}] \overset{[{\sf C}^\text{op},empty?]}\to [{\sf C}^\text{op},2]$, where $empty?\colon {\bf Set}\to 2$ does the obvious thing) then you can perform a Kan extension. Nontriviality of this extension is far from being granted, of course. :-)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian, when $2=\{0,1\}$, isn't it the case that the category $2^\mathsf{C}$ is the powerset of connected components of $\mathsf{C}$, not $\mathsf{C}\times\mathsf{C}$?

Comment: Sure, you're right. Functors to a discrete category descend to functors from the $\pi_0$